# Centering an image in a preset document

Tags: fonts, graphics

so i have this script that i use for my document header. https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmm9b.png

The problem is that it places the icon in the left corner of the document instead of the top of the writing along with the rest of the header.
https://gyazo.com/1bfee00b6034116c96d3407b18db2bfc

What should i do in order to place it correctly in the middle atop the writing?

Code:

```
\fontsize{11}{9}\selectfont
\parbox{1.5cm}{
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics{sigla_documente}
\end{center}
}
\parbox{17.4cm}{
\fontsize{11}{9}\selectfont
\centerline{Camera Executorilor Judec\v atore\c sti de pe l\^ ang\v a Curtea de Apel \CurteApel}
\centerline{\bf BIROUL EXECUTORILOR JUDEC\v ATORE\c STI ASOCIA\c TI}
\fontsize{11}{9}\selectfont
\centerline{\bf \MareNumeExecutor}

\begin{center}
\textbf{------------------------------------------------------------}
%\line(1,0){400}
\end{center}

\fontsize{10}{9}\selectfont
\centerline{\bf \ExecutorAdresa}
\centerline{\bf Cod po\c stal: \CodPostal, Tel./fax \TelFax}
\centerline{\bf Cod fiscal: \CIFExecutor,  email: \ExecutorEmail}
}

\leftline{\ }
\leftline{\ }
\fontsize{12}{10}\selectfont
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You can insert images directly into your post using the `Ctrl+G` shortcut when editing.

Comment: Please post your code instead of linking to an image of your code.

Comment: What document class are you using? What other packages have you loaded? Have you tried `\centering` instead?

Comment: Im new to Tex don t really understand what you mean by class or packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `\centering`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
\fontsize{11}{9}\selectfont


\begin{center}
\fontsize{11}{9}\selectfont
\centerline{Camera Executorilor Judec atore sti de pe l\^ ang a Curtea de Apel }
\centerline{\bf BIROUL EXECUTORILOR JUDEC ATORE STI ASOCIA TI}
\fontsize{11}{9}\selectfont
\centerline{\bf MareNumeExecutor}
\end{center}

\centering \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}

\begin{center}
\textbf{------------------------------------------------------------}
%\line(1,0){400}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\fontsize{10}{9}\selectfont
\centerline{\bf ExecutorAdresa}
\centerline{\bf Cod po stal: CodPostal, Tel./fax TelFax}
\centerline{\bf Cod fiscal: CIFExecutor,  email: ExecutorEmail}
\end{center}


\leftline{\ }
\leftline{\ }
\fontsize{12}{10}\selectfont
\end{document}
```

Comment: Doesn t work, when i try to run the script i get this error https://gyazo.com/de8cf357dfd8534a723e5d778e5c6ceb

Comment: @IvascuAlexandru The code I gave you works here, I don't know what is your full code. In order to help you you should paste the full tex code in your question.